# How to parse csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I need the first column of the table to be written to a variable, and the remaining columns (their number may vary) to be written to the list in order to get the desired value from the list. I'm trying to get email addresses, but the table itself is porridge, so every column needs to be checked.

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    name = list(next(reader))

    for items in list(reader):
        for item in items:
            if '@' in item:
                if not item in emails:
                    emails.append(item)
                

    with open('result.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        for email in emails:
            writer.writerow(
                (
                    name,
                    email
                )
            )
```

Input:

```
Наименование,Описание,Адрес,Комментарий к адресу,Почтовый индекс,Микрорайон,Район,Город,Округ,Регион,Страна,Часы работы,Часовой пояс,Телефон 1,E-mail 1,Веб-сайт 1,Instagram 1,Twitter 1,Facebook 1,ВКонтакте 1,YouTube 1,Skype 1,Широта,Долгота,2GIS URL
Магазин автозапчастей,,"Мира, 007",,655153,,,Черногорск,Черногорск городской округ,Республика Хакасия,Россия,Пн: 09:00-18:00; Вт: 09:00-18:00; Ср: 09:00-18:00; Чт: 09:00-18:00; Пт: 09:00-18:00; Сб: 09:00-18:00,+07:00,89130502009,grandauto007@mail.ru,http://avtomagazin.2gis.biz,,,,,,,53.805192,91.334047,https://2gis.com/firm/9711414977516651
Спектр-Авто,автотехцентр,"Вяткина, 4",1 этаж,655017,,,Абакан,Абакан городской округ,Республика Хакасия,Россия,Пн: 09:00-18:00; Вт: 09:00-18:00; Ср: 09:00-18:00; Чт: 09:00-18:00; Пт: 09:00-18:00; Сб: 09:00-18:00,+07:00,89233931771,+79233940022@yandex.ru,http://spectr-avto.2gis.biz,,,,,,,53.716581,91.45005,https://2gis.com/firm/70000001034136187
```

The result is:

```
['Наименование', 'Описание', 'Адрес', 'Комментарий к адресу', 'Почтовый индекс', 'Микрорайон', 'Район', 'Город', 'Округ', 'Регион', 'Страна', 'Часы работы', 'Часовой пояс', 'Телефон 1', 'E-mail 1', 'Веб-сайт 1', 'Instagram 1', 'Twitter 1', 'Facebook 1', 'ВКонтакте 1', 'YouTube 1', 'Skype 1', 'Широта', 'Долгота', '2GIS URL'];grandauto007@mail.ru
['Наименование', 'Описание', 'Адрес', 'Комментарий к адресу', 'Почтовый индекс', 'Микрорайон', 'Район', 'Город', 'Округ', 'Регион', 'Страна', 'Часы работы', 'Часовой пояс', 'Телефон 1', 'E-mail 1', 'Веб-сайт 1', 'Instagram 1', 'Twitter 1', 'Facebook 1', 'ВКонтакте 1', 'YouTube 1', 'Skype 1', 'Широта', 'Долгота', '2GIS URL'];+79233940022@yandex.ru
['Наименование', 'Описание', 'Адрес', 'Комментарий к адресу', 'Почтовый индекс', 'Микрорайон', 'Район', 'Город', 'Округ', 'Регион', 'Страна', 'Часы работы', 'Часовой пояс', 'Телефон 1', 'E-mail 1', 'Веб-сайт 1', 'Instagram 1', 'Twitter 1', 'Facebook 1', 'ВКонтакте 1', 'YouTube 1', 'Skype 1', 'Широта', 'Долгота', '2GIS URL'];zhvirblis_yuliya@mail.ru
```

Comment: Can you spell out what your desired output would be exactly? Your `name` variable is the whole header row in your files, and then you're printing it along with each e-mail, so the result is what I'd expect from your code. Did you mean to have pairs with the value from the first column plus any e-mail found on the line, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, what you really want to output is a two-column CSV, with names in the first column, which I assume come from the original CSV's first column, and e-mail in the second column.

If my assumptions are correct, this should work for you:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = list(next(reader))

    emails = []
    for items in reader:
        name = items[0]
        for item in items:
            if '@' in item:
                if not (name, item) in emails:
                    emails.append((name, item))
                

    with open('result.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        for email in emails:
            writer.writerow(email)
```

Output:

```
Магазин автозапчастей;grandauto007@mail.ru
Спектр-Авто;+79233940022@yandex.ru
```

Things I have changed in your code:

- The input CSV header is now read into `header` - did you want to do anything with that?
- The name is now set from `items[0]` for each row in the input CSV.
- The `emails` list is now a list of (name, email) pairs.
- Optimization detail: you don't need to turn `reader` into a list to iterate over it. Just say `for items in reader:`, it'll be more efficient since it will process each row as it reads it instead of storing them all into a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import petl

table = petl.fromcsv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
table2 = petl.addfield(table, 'email_address', lambda r: [r[r1] for r1 in petl.header(table) if '@' in r[r1]])
table3 = petl.cut(table2, 'Наименование', 'email_address')
petl.tocsv(table3, 'result.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', delimiter=';', write_header=True)
```

1. Load the CSV into a table
2. Create a new field(column) that is an aggregate of any field containing an email address
3. Reduce(cut) the table to only contain the 2 important fields: `'Наименование', 'email_address'`
4. Output the results to a CSV

Output:

```
Наименование;email_address
Магазин автозапчастей;['grandauto007@mail.ru']
Спектр-Авто;['+79233940022@yandex.ru']
```

Be sure to install `petl`:

```
pip install petl
```